# ext.net Javascript multiple function on click before event

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ext.net

I defined my own function and I want to return error when function1 AND function2 are not true

Code so far:

```
<Buttons>
        <ext:Button ID="ButtonSaveZgoda" runat="server" Text="Zapisz" Icon="Disk">
            <DirectEvents>
                <Click OnEvent="SaveZgody" Failure="Ext.Msg.alert('Komunikat', result.errorMessage);"
                    Before="return controlsAreValid(#{dateFieldDataDecyzjiNowaZgoda},#{ComboBoxZmianaNowaZgoda},#{FileUploadNowaZgoda} && hasSelection())"
                    Success="#{GridPanelLista}.reload();#{WindowAdd}.hide();">
                    <EventMask ShowMask="true" />
                    <ExtraParams>
                        <ext:Parameter Name="daneOsobowe" Value="Ext.encode(getDataFromDaneOsobowe())" Mode="Raw" />
                    </ExtraParams>
                </Click>
            </DirectEvents>
        </ext:Button>
    </Buttons>
```

It doesn't check the "hasSelection" function at all

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean to include "hasSelection()" as a arg in your controlsAreValid function.

Try:

```
Before="return controlsAreValid(#{dateFieldDataDecyzjiNowaZgoda},#{ComboBoxZmianaNowaZgoda},#{FileUploadNowaZgoda}); hasSelection()"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is caused by bad parenthesis, try this instead:

```
Before="return controlsAreValid(#{dateFieldDataDecyzjiNowaZgoda},#{ComboBoxZmianaNowaZgoda},#{FileUploadNowaZgoda}) && hasSelection()"
```